# Extract only numbers from a line of a txt file

Tags: sed, awk, grep, gawk

The output of certain command contains

```
 >> ..................546 Jobs Retrieved 
    List of jobs Retrieved: 1-4,6-12,14,2017-2018 ............
 >>> 30 Jobs Done
    Jobs terminated: retrieve them with: crab -getoutput <List of jobs>
    List of jobs: 203,376,578,765,803,809,811
.....................
```

And I want to extract only 203,376,578,765,803,809,811 that occurs after line 30 Jobs Done. And after that I neet to put this number as a string in certain variable to use this in some command. How can I do it.

I tried it in this way:

1. I put the output in a status.log file
2. $ sed -e '1,/Jobs Done/d' status.log | grep "List of jobs:"
       then I got only line 
       List of jobs: 578,765,811,836,1068,1096,1128 
   but I don't need the phrase "List of jobs"

Please help me.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Is the block you show repeated in your file, or just once? Does the "List of jobs" always come exactly 2 lines after "Jobs Done"?

Comment: List of Jobs comes several times but Jobs Done comes only one time in the output and yes the "List of jobs" always comes exactly 2 lines after "Jobs Done".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
awk '/30 Jobs Done/ {f=1;next} f && /List of jobs:/ {print $4;exit}' file
203,376,578,765,803,809,811
```

When it find `30 Jobs Done` it set flag `f` to true.
If it then finds `List of jobs:` and flag `f` is true, print field `4`

Comment: `30 Jobs Done` is probably a bad pattern `\d+ Jobs Done` would be much better. Also, an explanation how the script works would be nice.

Comment: @AaronDigulla I am not sure, OP asks specifically for data after `30 Jobs Done`  PS `\d+` did not work in my `awk`, so it would then be `[0-9]+ Jobs Done`

Comment: @Jotne Thanks. One more thing: now would like to put output of this command into a variable so I am using

jobs=$(awk '/Jobs Done/ {f=1;next} f && /List of jobs:/ {print $4;exit}' status.log)

But it is giving error as "Illegal variable name."

Comment: It works fine for me: `var=$(awk '/30 Jobs Done/ {f=1;next} f && /List of jobs:/ {print $4;exit}' file)` `echo $var
203,376,578,765,803,809,811`

Comment: I don't know why but it is not working for me.
Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Got the error. I am using tcsh shell so this is happening. 
now I am using 

set var="`awk '/Jobs Done/ {f=1;next} f && /List of jobs:/ {print $4;exit}' status.log`"

But I am not getting correct result
echo $var
List of jobs: 203,376,578,765,803,809,811

Comment: Got it:

set var='awk '/Jobs Done/ {f=1;next} f && /List of jobs:/ {print $4;exit}' status.log'

Comment: Do not write shell scripts in [t]csh. Google "csh why not".

Answer (score 1):

Using simple tools:

```
egrep '^\s+List of jobs: [0-9,]+$' status.log | cut -d: -f2
```

The pattern for `egrep` matches the whole line and the `cut` returns everything after the `:`.

That means you will get a leading space in the result. If that's a problem:

```
egrep '^\s+List of jobs: [0-9,]+$' status.log | cut -d: -f2 | cut -c2-
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
grep -A2 "Jobs Done" yourfile | awk '/List of jobs:/{print $4}'
```

Grab two lines following "Jobs Done" (`-A2`) and then look for "List of jobs" with `awk` and print 4th field.

Comment: +1 for simplicity. I don't know why people frown on using pipes. Wasn't that feature what made it so popular!